# How to preserve a tab in TabControl when using binding

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

So I have a `TabControl`. I want to bind the `ItemsSource` to my ViewModel collection so the tabs get added dynamically. Something like:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Cities}">
    <TabItem Header="Settings" x:Name="settingsTab" />
</TabControl>
```

Where `Cities` is an `ObservableCollection` of type `City`. However, I want the first tab to display `SettingsView`. The items from `Cities` should display `CityView`. The tab control is just a navigation panel and I'm basically trying to put `settings` on the first position, followed by a dynamic number of cities.

What's the most elegant solution to this? I would prefer to not pollute my view model with some random collection that contains the settings model followed by all the cities models.

Comment: use a `CompositeCollection`

Comment: @HighCore I never heard of that class before. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your tab control to be a list of cities, you need to use DataContext instead of ItemsSource. Then you can bind the cities object to a list view in the TabItems Content

example:

```
public class City
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string SettingOne {get;set;}
   public string SettingTwo {get;set;}
}

<TabControl DataContext="{Binding Path=Cities}">
    <TabItem Header="Settings" x:Name="settingsTab">
        <TabItem.Content>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SettingOne}"></TextBox>
                     ...
                 </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem.Content>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: I want one TabItem for (global app) settings, and then "x" number of TabItems for each city in "Cities". Settings view and city view differ, as well as their TabItem header templates.